# How to stop the repetition of inotify result?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

In this code, I am trying to monitor two paths at the same time. I used `while(1)` for this purpose. But the problem that I am facing is that whenever I run the code, it gives me the same result two times like this.

**Giving result**

```
Pathname1 "file" is modified 
Pathname1 "file" is modified
```

**Expected result**

```
Pathname1 "file" is modified
```

I debugged the code. After breaking the main function and stepping over it, the next command stops at this line `length = read(fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN )`. Whenever I break a line after this length variable command, the program starts and after modifying the file, the program stops at this line `struct inotify_event *event = ( struct inotify_event *)&buffer[i];` Although the program should not break.

**I also used  `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` instead of `IN_MODIFY` but no change in the result.**

```
typedef struct{
    int length, fd, wd1, wd2;
    char buffer[4096] __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(struct inotify_event))));
} notification;
notification inotify;

int getNotified(char *pathname1, char *pathname2){
    inotify.fd = inotify_init();
    inotify.wd1 = inotify_add_watch(inotify.fd, pathname1, IN_MODIFY);
    inotify.wd2 = inotify_add_watch(inotify.fd, pathname2, IN_MODIFY);

    while(1){
        inotify.length = read(inotify.fd, inotify.buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN); 
        int i = 0;
        while(i < inotify.length){     
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&inotify.buffer[i];
            if(event->len){
                if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY){
                    if(event->wd == inotify.wd1){
                        printf("Pathname1 '%s' is modified\n", event->name);
                        break;
                    }
                    if(event->wd == inotify.wd2){
                        printf("Pathname2 '%s' is modified\n", event->name);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
    }
    inotify_rm_watch(inotify.fd, inotify.wd1);
    inotify_rm_watch(inotify.fd, inotify.wd2);

    close(inotify.fd);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks:

- You should not "break" as you go out of the inside "while" loop and call *read()* again
- The **IN_MODIFY** event does not fill the *event->name* field (i.e. *event->len* = 0)
- The number of IN_MODIFY events depends on how you modify the files ("echo xxx >> file" = write only = 1 IN_MODIFY; "echo xxx > file" = truncate + write = 2 IN_MODIFY)

Here is a proposition for your program (with additional prints):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EVENT_BUF_LEN 4096
#define EVENT_SIZE sizeof(struct inotify_event)

typedef struct{
  int length, fd, wd1, wd2;
  char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN] __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(struct inotify_event))));
} notification;

notification inotify;

int getNotified(char *pathname1, char *pathname2){

  inotify.fd = inotify_init();
  inotify.wd1 = inotify_add_watch(inotify.fd, pathname1, IN_MODIFY);
  printf("wd1 = %d\n", inotify.wd1);
  inotify.wd2 = inotify_add_watch(inotify.fd, pathname2, IN_MODIFY);
  printf("wd2 = %d\n", inotify.wd2);

  while(1){
    inotify.length = read(inotify.fd, inotify.buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN); 
    int i = 0;
    printf("read() = %d\n", inotify.length);
    while(i < inotify.length){     
      struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&inotify.buffer[i];
      printf("event->len = %u\n", event->len);
      if(event->mask & IN_MODIFY){
        if(event->wd == inotify.wd1){
          printf("Pathname1 is modified\n");
        } else if (event->wd == inotify.wd2){
          printf("Pathname2 is modified\n");
        }
      }
      i += (EVENT_SIZE + event->len);
      printf("i=%d\n", i);
    }
  }
  inotify_rm_watch(inotify.fd, inotify.wd1);
  inotify_rm_watch(inotify.fd, inotify.wd2);

  close(inotify.fd);
  exit(0);
}



int main(void)
{
  getNotified("/tmp/foo", "/tmp/bar");

  return 0;

} // main
```

Here is an example of execution:

```
$ gcc notif.c -o notif
$ > /tmp/foo
$ > /tmp/bar
$ ./notif 
wd1 = 1
wd2 = 2

====== Upon "> /tmp/foo": 1 event (truncate operation)
read() = 16
event->len = 0
Pathname1 is modified
i=16

====== Upon "echo qwerty > /tmp/foo": 2 events (write operation, one event for truncate operation and one for the write of "qwerty" at the beginning of the file)
read() = 16
event->len = 0
Pathname1 is modified
i=16
read() = 16
event->len = 0
Pathname1 is modified
i=16

====== Upon "echo qwerty >> /tmp/foo": 1 event (write of "qwerty" at the end of the file)
read() = 16
event->len = 0
Pathname1 is modified
i=16
```

Comment: @richardk. Sorry but it is still giving me the same result.

Comment: I updated my answer as IN_MODIFY generates 2 events upon write operation

Comment: @richardk. I don't want to get two event notifications.  I just want one at a time. But it is showing me `Pathname1 is modified` and again `Pathname1 is modified`. I just want Pathnam1 is modified only once.

Comment: I updated the code with expected result. Please check it.

Comment: I just want the write operation to appear.

Comment: Yes. This what is done except if you type something like "echo data > file" : this triggers 2 IN_MODIFY as there are a truncate + a write.

Comment: How can I get only a written event, not a truncate event?

Comment: Don't truncate the file ;-) With "echo data >> file" you don't trigger a truncate.

Comment: I just want it to show me a written event. One event and only one event. I want to show the user that the `Pathname1 is modified`. It should not be repeated multiple times. I am facing this problem for two days and didn't find a solution. Please show me the code, so that a user could only see one event. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the two pathnames refer to the same inode, then `inotify.wd1 == inotify.wd2`.  In that case, because you have

```c
    if (event->wd == inotify.wd1) {
        printf("Pathname1 '%s' is modified\n", event->name);
    }
    if (event->wd == inotify.wd2) {
        printf("Pathname2 '%s' is modified\n", event->name);
    }
```

*both* bodies would be executed; but the outputs would differ (`Pathname1 ...` and `Pathname2 ...`).

You really should be monitoring the directories the files reside in, rather than the actual pathnames, so you can catch rename events also.  (Many editors create a temporary file, and rename or hardlink the temporary file over the old file, so that programs see either the old or the new file, and never a mix of the two.)

Consider the following program, which does not exhibit any undue duplication of events:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#define  _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t  done = 0;

static void handle_done(int signum)
{
    done = signum;
}

static int install_done(int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = handle_done;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    return sigaction(signum, &act, NULL);
}

struct monitor {
    /* Supplied by caller */
    const char  *directory;
    const char  *pathname;
    int        (*modified)(struct monitor *);
    int        (*completed)(struct monitor *);
    /* Reserved for internal use */
    int          dirwatch;
};

int monitor_files(struct monitor *const list, const size_t count)
{
    char   *events_ptr = NULL;
    size_t  events_len = 65536;
    size_t  i;
    int     err;

    /* Verify sane parameters */
    if (count < 1) {
        errno = ENOENT;
        return -1;
    } else
    if (!list) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (!list[i].directory || !list[i].directory[0]) {
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }
        if (!list[i].pathname || !list[i].pathname[0]) {
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }
        list[i].dirwatch = -1;
    }

    /* Obtain a descriptor for inotify event queue */
    int  queue = inotify_init1(IN_CLOEXEC);
    if (queue == -1) {
        /* errno set by inotify_init1() */
        return -1;
    }

    /* Use a reasonable dynamically allocated buffer for events */
    events_ptr = malloc(events_len);
    if (!events_ptr) {
        close(queue);
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Add a watch for each directory to be watched */
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        list[i].dirwatch = inotify_add_watch(queue, list[i].directory, IN_CLOSE_WRITE | IN_MOVED_TO | IN_MODIFY);
        if (list[i].dirwatch == -1) {
            err = errno;
            close(queue);
            free(events_ptr);
            errno = err;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* inotify event loop */
    err = 0;
    while (!done) {
        ssize_t  len = read(queue, events_ptr, events_len);
        if (len == -1) {
            /* Interrupted due to signal delivery? */
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            /* Error */
            err = errno;
            break;
        } else
        if (len < -1) {
            /* Should never occur */
            err = EIO;
            break;
        } else
        if (len == 0) {
            /* No events watched anymore */
            err = 0;
            break;
        }

        char *const end = events_ptr + len;
        char       *ptr = events_ptr;
        while (ptr < end) {
            struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)ptr;

            /* Advance buffer pointer for next event */
            ptr += sizeof (struct inotify_event) + event->len;
            if (ptr > end) {
                close(queue);
                free(events_ptr);
                errno = EIO;
                return -1;
            }

            /* Call all event handlers, even duplicate ones */
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (event->wd == list[i].dirwatch && !strcmp(event->name, list[i].pathname)) {
                    if ((event->mask & (IN_MOVED_TO | IN_CLOSE_WRITE)) && list[i].completed) {
                        err = list[i].completed(list + i);
                        if (err)
                            break;
                    } else
                    if ((event->mask & IN_MODIFY) && list[i].modified) {
                        err = list[i].modified(list + i);
                        if (err)
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (err)
                break;
        }
        if (err)
            break;
    }

    close(queue);
    free(events_ptr);

    errno = 0;
    return err;
}

static int report_modified(struct monitor *m)
{
    printf("%s/%s: Modified\n", m->directory, m->pathname);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}

static int report_completed(struct monitor *m)
{
    printf("%s/%s: Completed\n", m->directory, m->pathname);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct monitor  watch[2] = {
        { .directory = ".",
          .pathname  = "file1",
          .modified  = report_modified,
          .completed = report_completed },
        { .directory = ".",
          .pathname  = "file2",
          .modified  = report_modified,
          .completed = report_completed }
    };
    int  err;

    if (install_done(SIGINT) == -1 ||
        install_done(SIGHUP) == -1 ||
        install_done(SIGTERM) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set signal handlers: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "To stop this program, press Ctrl+C, or send\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "INT, HUP, or TERM signal (to process %ld).\n", (long)getpid());
    fflush(stderr);

    err = monitor_files(watch, 2);
    if (err == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error monitoring files: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else
    if (err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Monitoring files failed [%d].\n", err);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you compile it using e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 example.c -o example` and run it via `./example`, it will report IN_MODIFY events (as "Modified") and IN_CLOSE_WRITE and IN_MOVED_TO events (as "Completed") for `file1` and `file2` in the same directory (current working directory).  To exit the program, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

(Note that we should probably add third event type, "Deleted", corresponding to `IN_DELETE` and `IN_MOVED_FROM` events.)

If you open `file1` or `file2` in say a text editor, saving the file generates one or more Modified (IN_MODIFY) events, and exactly one Completed (IN_CLOSE_WRITE or IN_MOVED_TO) event.  This is because each open()/truncate()/ftruncate() syscall that causes the file to be truncated, generates one IN_MODIFY event for that file; as does every underlying write() syscall that modifies the file contents.  Thus, it is natural to receive multiple IN_MODIFY events when some process modifies the file.

If you have multiple `struct monitor` entries in the list with the same effective directory and the same pathname, the example program will provide multiple events for them.  If you wish to avoid this, just make sure that whenever `.pathname` matches, the two get differing `.dirwatch`es.

Comment: After running, it just shows me the `fprintf`, and after that no monitoring is showing.

Comment: @Skywifibrand: You need to run it in one terminal window.  Open another terminal window, change (`cd`) to the same working directory, and then run say `touch file1`, `date > file2`, `mv file2 file1`, or `cp file1 file2`.  Each of these wll be reported.  (I have verified the code works correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

rewriting the `while()` loop into a `for()` loop, and flattening out the `if()`s"

---

```
while(1){
    int i ;
    struct inotify_event *event ;

    inotify.length = read(inotify.fd, inotify.buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN);

    for(i=0; i < inotify.length; i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len ) {
        event = (struct inotify_event *)&inotify.buffer[i];

        if (!event->len) continue;
        if (!(event->mask & IN_MODIFY)) continue;

        if (event->wd == inotify.wd1){
            printf("Pathname1 '%s' is modified\n", event->name);
            continue;
        }

        if (event->wd == inotify.wd2){
            printf("Pathname2 '%s' is modified\n", event->name);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it is still giving me the same result.